# JS Regexp: \b for hyphenated words

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript regexp, what can I use in place of \b to get the same effect but on words that may be *hyphenated*?

(This question is directed at readers familiar with \b and with hyphenation, and so does not provide examples.)

UPDATE

Addison's `(?<!-)\b(?!-)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/TtvE3E/1) is a partial solution for PCRE. It falls short on `-500`, by [losing the boundary](https://regex101.com/r/qRzzck/2) that [\b delivers](https://regex101.com/r/qRzzck/3). It [doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/fpcL5C/1) on lookbehind-less JavaScript.

---

Comment: [^\w-]+ perhaps

Comment: I know what \b and hyphenation are but I don't understand what you want. Instead of wasting time saying you won't provide examples, you could have written an example.

Comment: Alex, "[^\w-]+ perhaps" No, that https://regex101.com/r/2ef6UW/1 is nothing like \b https://regex101.com/r/1QTt8p/2

Comment: Isn't *matching* approach easier? See [the `\w+(?:-\w+)*` demo](https://regex101.com/r/tpYRdR/1). Please share the expected output for the sample input you shared with the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create your own version of `\b` in regex flavors like JavaScript that don't support lookbehind.  `\b` matches at a position.  It needs to check the character (or lack thereof) before and after that position in order to determine whether the position should be matched.  This requires both lookahead and lookbehind.

You can match hyphenated words (ASCII only) with this regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z\-]+\b
```

This regex will allow hyphens before and after the word but does not include those in the match.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the `\b` expression, but modify it to be a little more fussy. Add a negative [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to it, so that it doesn't appear beside a hypen:

```
(?<!-)\b(?!-)
```

[Try it on Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/TtvE3E/1)

Note that this might cause problems with words such as `-500`, depending on what behaviour you want. You might want there to be a boundary before or after the hyphen (or not at all).

#### UPDATE

The regex gets much more complex, since there is not ordinarily a boundary before a hyphen, meaning one must be added.

```
(?<!-)\b(?!-)|\B(?=-\w)
```

The second condition adds a boundary wherever there is a non-word boundary followed by a hyphen and a word character. It's very explicit, but this is the only case it happens.

Comment: Yeah - I wasn't sure what you wanted to happen there. If you describe the functionality you want in the question, you'll get an answer that accommodates it. Examples really, really help.

Comment: Okay, it gets significantly more complex now, since we want boundaries in places where there are ordinarily none, but [this is it](https://regex101.com/r/TtvE3E/3)

Comment: @ChrisJJ - Please edit your question, and put some examples in. I'm putting in effort to help, and this could be a question others ask in the future

Comment: those use lookbehind, which JavaScript doesn't allow.

Comment: I made a bit of research and as far as I read this is literally impossible without using lookbehinds, meaning it cannot be accomplished in Javascript. You could look for libraries that implements pcre like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcre) maybe but that's getting complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I've come to the same conclusion, @NicolasMaltais. I'm just trying to figure out how to break the news to OP

Comment: @NicolasMaltais, Thanks. Addison "If you describe the functionality you want in the question, you'll get an answer that accommodates it." You'd hope. My question says three times it is for JavaScript. Your answer is apparently for PCRE and doesn't work in JavaScript.